# Media player with 4k and display port

Tags: hdmi, video, display-port

I have a 4k monitor that has HDMI and display port. The problem is that it is HDMI 1.4 and is only able to display 4k content at 30Hz. For me that is unacceptable. Over display port, 4k is displayed at 60Hz which delivers a far better experience.

I want to use this monitor as a TV and need a player that plays 4k content at 60Hz and has display port. Also a digital audio output would be a pre.

My preference is a single device with a remote control. But any alternative is welcome, including building something my own. However consider the following:

1. It has to be silent (no annoying fans)
2. Starts up quickly and is instantly available as media player
3. Software should be easy to use
4. It is controllable with a remote control
5. The price is like, say an Apple TV 4k (a bit more is acceptable)

Any advice is welcome too, except buying a new monitor ;-)

Comment: What 4K content are we talking about? Blu-rays? Web content? Cable TV?

Comment: This is for streaming files from a NAS or internet. Blu-ray would be nice but not essential.

Comment: @JMY1000 To add to my previous comment: If it can only play files from an internal hard drive or external USB drive I would be happy too, but I would rather stream it from elsewhere.

Comment: Are there any particular form factor constraints? Would you be willing to put something together yourself?

Comment: What about loading your own software?

Comment: Yes building something my own is a possibility if it’s only a matter of putting some components together in a housing, install something that works instantly as media player and if it’s affordable. The problem is, I have no idea what to buy or install and I have no budget or time for experimenting. So any advice in that direction is very welcome.

Comment: Okay, back to the form factor constraint issue. How big/small do you want the computer to be? How big/small is acceptable, if not ideal? Also, would you be willing to buy used hardware?

Comment: I’m looking into mini PC’s now, like Intel NUC and Shuttle. But the ones with (mini) DisplayPort are a few years old. It still is an option and yes, that makes buying used hardware also an option.

Comment: Gotcha, that's mostly what I've been focusing on too. However, an equivalent SFF desktop or laptop will probably be much cheaper work the same specs if you can stomach the larger size.

Comment: @JMY1000, the form factor is a small box (see previous comment), preferably flat as long as that doesn’t limit the options too much. No tower PC or NAS like system and not that powerful that it needs a noisy fan.

Comment: @JMY1000, If a desktop or laptop makes it easier and cheaper, than that is also a possibility. But I’m worried about noise and the software. I want it instant on and ready as media-player.